# Using HIKVISION DS-K1T671TM-3XF Face Reorganization Terminal in C#

Tags: hikvision

I want HIKVISION DS-K1T671TM-3XF Face Reorganization Terminal in C#.

When ever user face recognition happens I want to capture that and match face in C# code, how to do this?

Any help ideas will really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to achieve this? or are you able to make any post call from C#? i am trying similar call but getting bad request message with every post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is work around for this, I actually wanted this events to be captured using my own code.

Hikvision devices do this on their own and insert entries in their in / out logs, I have imported these logs using hikvision SDK and that solves my problem. As I wanted that data.

If anyone looking for in / out data then we don't need to capture these events, we can directly to device using Hikvision SDK, and get all the events data.